# Testing a string for a regex pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to process further in my function when an input string matches following regex pattern:

> whitespace_or_beginning_of_line word_from_letters slash
> word_from_letters whitespace_or_end_of_line

I've tried:

```
import re

text = "[url=}}{{cz.csob.cebmobile://deeplink?screen=AL03&tab=overview/detail/cards/standing_orders]"

if re.search(r" [a-aZ-Z]/[a-aZ-Z] ", text) or re.search(r"\n[a-aZ-Z]/[a-aZ-Z]\n", text):
   ...process further (do some logic)
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that's correct actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)
```

In Python:

```py
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+(?!\S)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bZV8uO/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `/` - a slash
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary.